# the program does not return the expected curve

Tags: assets, between, spread

I made a pine-script v4 program. My objective is to make relative value. The program is calculating and drawing a curve which determine the spread in % between two shares (here Apple and Microsoft) with the same start point. The problem is that the result is wrong. This is my code:

```
//@version=4
study("Apple-Microsoft", overlay=false)
Apple=(security("AAPL","D",close)/security("AAPL","D",2020-01-01-09-30)-1)*100
Microsoft=(security("MSFT","D",close)/security("MSFT","D",2020-01-01-09-30)-1)*100
spread=Apple-Microsoft
plot(spread)
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: please define the logic to be coded properly.
what is the purpose of passing expression as "2020-01-01-09-30" in security function ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.